# How can I bundle JavaScript files under /vendor in an ember-cli project?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-cli, babeljs, rollupjs

Let's say I have an ES6 library "foo" under my `/vendor` directory in an EmberJS project constructed using the latest `ember-cli` (at the time of this writing 2.4.3). Assume that foo is a library with multiple files, e.g. `bar.js`, `baz.js`, etc. and they all export something.

I would like to take `vendor/foo/bar.js`, `vendor/foo/baz.js`, etc. and bundle them into a distribution file, e.g. `vendor/foo/dist/foo-bundle.js` that I can then import into Ember with:

```
app.import("vendor/foo/dist/foo-bundle.js");
```

This appears like it should be possible with a bundler and/or transpiler (like [Babel](https://babeljs.io/)), but it isn't clear to me what tools I should use and in what combination. Does Ember have a built in tool for doing what I want through ember-cli (if it does, I must be blind)? Should I be using an external bundler like [webpack](https://webpack.github.io/), [browserify](http://browserify.org/), or [rollup](https://github.com/rollup/rollup)?

In general there seems to be a lot of noise around JavaScript tooling making it difficult for me to understand what choices I have for this problem and how to properly leverage them. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

---

**Some notes that may be helpful...**

I have tried a few things, so far:

I have tried just importing the `main.js` file, in hopes that EmberJS would also walk the dependency tree and import any other files that were referenced in `import` statements. This only imported the `main.js` file and no other dependencies.

I've looked at [broccoli-es6modules](https://github.com/ember-cli/broccoli-es6modules) and had errors when running it, but it also uses [esperanto](https://github.com/esperantojs/esperanto) which is deprecated in favor of rollup.

I've also tried using rollup directly, with a minor degree of success, but often times my `bundle.js` output is empty and doesn't include the code from `bar.js` or `baz.js` because I've only imported them in the entry point (e.g. `main.js`):

```
main.js
-------
import bar from './bar.js';
import baz from './baz.js';

bar.js
------
export default function bar() {
  ...
}

baz.js
------
export default function baz() {
   ...
}
```

I have found if my `main.js` includes a function that calls either code from `bar` or `baz` I get more than an empty bundle, but if foo is just a collection of scripts from a third-party vendor that have no "application entry point", aside from what amounts to something like a manifest file, rollup seems to be the wrong choice for what I'm looking for.

Thanks again!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(Updated with the latest options.)

There are a few options.

1. If `baz.js` and `bar.js` are your own modules and code, the best if you just place them in `app/my-awesome-module` folder. You can use ES6 import to import in other place, where you would like to use them. Ember CLI will transpile, concatenate and minify them automatically.
2. If you would like to use 3rd party modules or solutions, check out http://emberobserver.com, most of the popular library already converted to Ember Addon, so you can install them with `ember install`.
3. Use `ember-auto-import` in your project and import libraries as normal ES6 module like this: `import MyCoolModule from "my-cool-module";`

Comment: Ah, OK. So if for whatever reason I have multiple source files that are either my own or a non-distributed third party (i.e. not available in a bower or npm package) the best bet would be to import them directly to the application under `/app` or to create an add-on that wrapped them What is the point of `/vendor` then? Is is legacy?

Comment: Actually, you are right. There are still some edge case, when `/vendor` is the best place. If you cannot create a package from your in-house private project (however, it is the best if you could), vendor is still legit. Is your package ES6 module or ES5 vanilla js?

Comment: The question actually stems from more of an academic curiosity than practical necessity right now. I was experimenting with EmberJS, and was trying to understand all the possible ways to get code into the application in as compact a form as possible and found the hypothetical case of a modular ES6 library under `/vendor` particularly confusing--especially as it does (or doesn't) relate to the `vendor.js` file. As far as I can tell, getting code that needs to be transpiled and transpiled (or vice-versa) actually into the `vendors.js` file is somewhat... difficult.

Comment: (I'm building my master project in Ember.js, so any academic curiosity is welcome. :) I use Ember.js more than 4 years now, and I don't really remember, ever used that vendor folder. It is just there as legacy. Most of your external dependency could be added as bower/npm/ember package... From ember-cli website: `vendor/ - vendor specific files, such as stylesheets, fonts, external libs etc.`, so they suggested as a placeholder for complex code... and probably a vendor package would be already transpiled, minified, etc...

Comment: Thanks! That's basically the same conclusion I've come to. I've only started looking at Ember recently to replace the front end of a project currently using Twig (PHP) + Backbone. I appreciate your help in this matter, it's been really useful for coming to a better understanding of my build process and dependencies.

Comment: I wrote a quite complex tutorial, if you would like to dig deep in Ember.js. It is totally free. :) http://yoember.com

Comment: Awesome! Thanks, I'll check it out.

Comment: @chiara-ani Thanks for the heads up. I updated the post based on the latest options. ;)